# Why is a number in my link text appearing as *************** (stars)?

Tags: hyperlink, html-email, credit-card, digits

I have posted this as, although I worked out the answer, I could not find anything about it in a Google/stackoverflow search. I hope it might help someone in the future.

My C# MVC app generates a link and emails it to the user. In the email the html is simply a link tag with the url used as the href and the link text.

In the email in Outlook the link displays as below:

```
http://mydomain.com/Foo/Bar?id=6***************
```

When you hover over the link it shows as

```
http://mydomain.com/Foo/Bar?id=6523054102058710
```

The numbers should always show, otherwise the user may be suspicious.

Comment: Couldn't replicate this locally. Are you sure its not your Exchange controller that's sanitising the links? Code to replicate may help.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the number I was generating was 16 digits, inadvertently the same as a credit/debit card number. This meant that some email clients were hiding the number to protect privacy.

To solve the problem I simply changed the number of digits.

Comment: Awesome contribution. Have you seen this problem in other webmail (than Outlook)? :)

Comment: I suspect although you identified the issue, you misdiagnosed the cause. Much more likely to be your mail server that is sanitising the digits. If you're using a corporate mailserver then speak to the administrator. My wager is that they have something in place to sanitise anything that looks like a credit card number (for PCIDSS reasons).